# Which multi-user operating systems allow a user to see the current command line of other users?

Tags: command-line, operating-systems

I was reading the [manpage of `unzip`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/unzip.1.html), and ran into the following

```
-P password
       use password to decrypt encrypted zipfile entries (if  any).   THIS
       IS  INSECURE!   Many  multi-user operating systems provide ways for
       any user to see the current command line of any other user; even on
       stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder
       peeking.
```

While the security precaution of not typing passwords in clear text (and having them end up in shell history) is of course true, I find it hard to believe that there are operating systems out there where *any user* can see the command line of *any other user*. Could someone give me an example (legacy systems included)?

---

I believe `ps`, `top`, etc. are the answer for UNIX.

Comment: keyboard driver)

Comment: @STTR I know little about hardware so I'm not sure if keyboard driver gives all users equal and full access, but that's certainly not an OS and there's no tty attached to it.

Comment: Just a note, if you want to keep a command from going into the bash history, precede the command with a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that on Unix/Linux systems using [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) might potentially expose user interaction. The logic being that `lsof` shows a list of open files on the system. And perhaps if one is unzipping a huge file then it would still be open for long enough for someone to notice and then peek at activity. Heck, it would be fairly trivial to write a Bash script and run it every minute or so via a cron job to collect an ongoing log of open file activity.

But that still rings false to me. I mean `lsof` does potentially expose something like inline MySQL passwords this way. But I am not 100% as to whether a normal user without `sudo`/root rights would be able to see `lsof` activity from other users like that.

Comment: Uh you're definitely on the right track. I think `lsof` shows open files of other users and you don't need elevated privilege (tested on my institution's server). Similarly, `ps` and `top` reveal other user's command lines.

Comment: I further checked the manpages of `ps`, `top` and `lsof` and found no mention of privilege. There's also this question: [How to make a process invisible to other users?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/how-to-make-a-process-invisible-to-other-users). So I guess the command lines are indeed visible to everyone on UNIX systems. Hmm, big surprise.

Comment: I found out about `ttysnoop` and `conspy` however I'm not sure whether or not they require root privileges.

Comment: Which are the option to pass to `lsof` that allow to see the parameter of the command line? with e.g. `lsof -a +c0 /dev/null` I'm able to see long command name but not parameter passed to the command. What did I miss? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Some (and I believe not all) Linux ways to see the command `zip -PThat_Password ...` of another user without *root privileges*:

- `cat  /proc/24695/cmdline` if the PID is 24695...

  > zip-P**That_Password**

  *Note:* It's without spaces but it's possible to guess the password however
- `grep -H  -e "zip" /proc/[0-9]*/cmdline`

  > Binary file /proc/24695/cmdline matches

  well if it works `cat` it works everything else *text* based ...
- `pgrep -a zip` the option -a  lists the full command line as well as the process ID. (not always available on old version [e.g. <2008] of `pgrep`)

  > 24695 zip -P **That_Password**

and of course the *op* mentioned

- `ps -aux | grep zip`

  > **That_User** 24695  1.9  0.0  15012  1192 pts/40   T    12:37   0:45 zip -P **That_Password**
- `top -c -b -n 1 | grep zip` that answer with something like

  > 24695 **That_User**  20   0   15012   1192    820 T   0.0  0.0   0:45.12 zip -P **That_Password**

Comment: @JakeGould At least on my systems the command like `cat /proc/24695/cmdline` give output without spaces...

Answer (score 4):

Unix allows "ps".  Also, Unix commonly has a "w" command that will show what users are running.  "w" might commonly chop off commands based on terminal size, but that can be overridden.  (One easy way may be to just use a wider terminal.)

This will probably also affect multiple Unix-like systems (Linux, BSD systems, Solaris, etc.)

I believe that Microsoft Windows would also show this in the Task Manager.  Well, maybe that is less common with Windows Vista and User Account Control, as User Account Control may be needed.  But back in the days on WinXP/Server2003 and earlier, such restrictions may have been more lax.  There's a reason why NET USE started supporting an asterisk and then prompting the user for a password.  With:

```
WMIC /NODE:ComputerName PROCESS LIST
```

a user probably doesn't even need to be on the same computer to see a command that is run.  Offhand, I'd suspect that multiple of TaskList, TList, and PSList (all distributed freely by Microsoft) probably also support the ability to see what is happening, regardless of what user is running.  At least, users with Administrator privileges, which was more common on pre-Vista operating systems.  (In Win9x, the general standard was that all users had Administrator-like abilities.)  Keep in mind that Info-Zip, which is the documentation you're quoting, is quite a bit older than WinXP.  Offhand I think it's older than Win95.

With older multi-user systems, secrecy was not as big of a concern.  Being able to see what the computer is doing, including what commands other users were running, was probably viewed as a positive feature, not a negative breach in security.  Perhaps a more applicable question is: Is there any major multi-user OS that did not support users being able to see what commands are run on the computer?

The safer approach is to never put sensitive passwords on a command line.  Another option may be to put passwords in a file, and then specify that file on the command line.  e.g.:

```
type pwfile | command
```

At least that way, permissions based on the filesystem implementation will likely offer some protection.

Comment: In order to see another user's processes on Windows, you must be an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps ax
```

on Unix/Linux and similar.